# ttf-mscorefonts-installer folder empty

Tags: fonts

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I donwloaded the `mscorefonts` installer, in order to use Arial and Arial bold fonts, and accepted the EULA agreement.

But I can't use the fonts, and when I got into `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts`, the `msttcorefonts` folder is empty.

I've tried reinstalling both manually and automatically and updating it, but neither appear to work. Does anyone know the `ttf-font` files for Arial and Arial bold?

Comment: I've downloaded nautilus via the software center, but I can't use it, so I don't now how to get it to work other than completely reinstall crouton, which is a lot of effort

Comment: Just a warning, I'm new to this, and I won't understand a lot of stuff, so if you could dumb it down a lot I'd be really thankful

Comment: @JoelClark copy both fonts in msttcorefonts folder and open in font viewer and install